# multibit isnt showing my bitcoin as spendable

Tags: multibit

I sent some btc to my multibit wallet a while back to try out the software.  multibit tells me that the transaction has only been seen by 4 peers since 21 may 2013. however blockchain.info tells me confirmed by 36840 peers. the part of my transaction shows unspent bitcoin. how do i get multibit to see my bitcoin as a valid transaction and allow me to spend some or recover it in a blockchain.info wallet?

Comment: Is Multibit synchronized?

Comment: Patience, grasshopper.